# Amazon Web Services AMI Image Issue (Host not Responding to Requests)

Tags: django, apache, amazon-ec2, mod-wsgi

I had a Micro Instance from which I created an AMI Image. I then upgraded to a Large Instance with this Image in tow and assigned an elastic IP Address. I changed my A Name to point to the new IP and, according to a reverse DNS lookup service, my DNS appears to have propagated correctly (cranku.com).

I created a virtual host for the domain name and restarted apache. And, yet, the domain is not responding to my requests. Could I be missing something here?

I am deploying Django with Mod Wsgi on Apache. I have moved MYSQL to a mounted EBS volume but that seems to be working here (and it worked on the instance from which I created the AMI). Restarting Apache works (/etc/apache/init.d/restart). Do I have to configure it in any other ways.

Any clues on how to proceed?

Comment: Does the domain respond from _other_ machines? I'm curious if your local systems have cached the DNS request. What is the TTL on your DNS entries? Have you waited at least that long before testing? :)

Comment: Hmm, never even considered TTL before. It appears to be 1 hour and that has definitely been exceeded :)

Comment: I also did test it out on another machine. Still no dice

Comment: I freaking love you man. I didn't realize I hadn't enabled port 80. worked. Genius!

Comment: You can put that in an answer sarnold and I'll give you the proper credit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reach your `ssh` server on the machine, but attempts to reach the webserver here are failing too, in a manner that makes me think the packets are being `DROP`ed rather than `REJECT`ed. [Have you authorized port 80](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonEC2/dg/2006-10-01/CLTRG-authorize.html)?